# BLOCKING the input of numbers in the textarea/textbox

Tags: javascript, html

```
  <textarea rows="4" cols="20" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace([0-9], '')">
  </textarea>
```

this is my codes now I need to block the input of numbers zero to nine
any idea on what to change in my codes

as much as possible I want to insert the code inside the < ....... >

Comment: Since you've accepted my answer, I've updated it with a more-professional-looking method. Just wanted to make sure you see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regex. This shows the number, then deletes it. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8KD6e/1/)

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="20" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/\d+/g, '')"></textarea>
```

**Cleaner method:** use `onkeydown` and return false based on keyCode. [Fiddle with onkeydown](http://jsfiddle.net/8KD6e/3/)

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="20" onkeydown="if((event.keyCode>47&&event.keyCode<58)||(event.keyCode>95&&event.keyCode<106))return false"></textarea>
```

Note: you have to handle the top row of numbers as well as the keypad in this case, hence the two sets of conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this code :

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="20" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[0-9]/g, '')"></textarea>
```

[Try in Fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/8KD6e/2/)